# Open source Siri clone

Tags: ruby, open-source, automation, siri

I'm thinking about creating an open source Siri clone in Ruby (not a Siri proxy, not the voice recognition part, but the "parse a question or command and take an action or return a response"). Similar to hubot, but more like Siri, and make it a library that could be included in any Ruby project. Before I go to the work of doing this, I want to make sure something like this doesn't exist or hasn't been started yet. Do you know of an open source Siri clone?

Comment: This is very general. You might try searching large project sites like [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/).

Comment: take a good NLP course or six first

Comment: I've already done a bit of searching on google and rubygems

Comment: An open-source Siri server is being worked on - see here: http://www.sirihacks.net/2012/02/01/eichhoernchens-open-source-siri-server-might-soon-replace-siriproxy-servers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Florian Hanke has an open source project called James, which I've seen demoed and has similar goals, though the things it "does" are scripted in ruby according to your own needs.  Sort of like a speech-recognition route map with a state machine.

https://github.com/floere/james

Comment: That looks pretty cool. Thanks for sharing. I will have to check it out.

Comment: what about patents? http://www.google.com/patents/US6839669